# Testcafe with Testrail integration is not updating the results

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, testrail

I'm trying to integrate testcafe with testrail. I have created a test run in testrail with some test cases.

I have tried as given here by changing the environment variables and test description

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html-testrail
```

I have made changes to the description as below

```
test('Smoke | Verify the Login Page | C1232145 ', async t=> { ... });
```

But the test cases didn't get updated in test rail.

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe officially does not provide integration with TestRail. The `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` is an external module so it's better to contact its author - https://www.npmjs.com/~miteshonly

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-testrail-simple, which was created with a simple configuration in mind and not to add meta information to the test case name.